# existe (se puede hacer) un spritesheet de sonido? UNITY3d

Tags: unity3d

Estoy haciendo un juego en Unity 3d, de tipo plataformas, con scroll hacia la derecha. Ahora estoy con la parte de sonido del juego, y no se si existe algo parecido al termino que pongo en la pregunta. Intento explicarlo (seguro que tiene un nombre, pero lo desconozco, yo lo he llamado `spriteSheet de sonido`).

En el caso de los sprites, podemos utilizar una unica imagen que dividimos con el editor de imagenes del Unity3d, para poder usar cada "trozo" de imagen, como una secuencia, o una parte de animacion, plataforma, etc.

La pregunta es si existe algo parecido al spriteSheet, pero para audio.

Tengo un audio que puedo ejecutar en cualquier momento con:

```
public AudioClip miSonido;
void Start () {
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update () {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        source.Play(miSonido);
    }
}
```

}

Lo que me interesaria es poder acceder a una parte de ese sonido, y reproducirlo en bucle. De tal manera que luego, en otro punto (por ej, al colisionar con un arbol que tengo en una parte del escenario) se empiece a reproducir otra parte del sonido. Pero esto siendo el mismo archivo de origen.

vamos, que si existe algo como esto:

```
source.Play(miSonido, startAt, endAt, bucle)
```

(Esto ultimo me lo he inventado, es mas o menos para indicar lo que busco)

No tendria problema para averiguar el posible `startAt`, el `endAt`  Puedo utilizar Audacity u otro editor de sonido para localizar el momento de tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer en estos casos es siempre ir a buscar en el Manual de Unity si existe algo que directamente te sirva para tu problema. Como estas usando Audio, miraremos en Audio Source

[Audio Source Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html)

Aqui puedes ver las diferentes funciones y variables de las que dispone, si te fijas bien hay una variable llamada time que indica el tiempo del audio. Y podemos ver tambien una función llamada SetScheduledEndTime.

Algo así debería funcionar:

```
 float startTime = 3.0f
 float endTime= 6.0f

 source.time = startTime;
 source.Play();
 source.SetScheduledEndTime(AudioSettings.dspTime+(endTime-startTime ));
```

Comment: ufff. llega a ser un perro y me muerde... He estado mirando siempre AudioClip y no me he fijado en el AudioSource. Y encima es el reproductor (que es donde tiene sentido). Gracias @cjf93.